# How to get the configurations from within a module import in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Let's say I have my module defined as below:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      // Use ConfigService here
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
    PrismaModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthResolver, AuthService, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Now how can I get the `secretKey` from the `ConfigService` in here?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You have to use `registerAsync`, so you can inject your `ConfigService`. With it, you can import modules, inject providers and then use those providers in a factory function that returns the configuration object:

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    secretOrPrivateKey: configService.getString('SECRET_KEY'),
    signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
    },
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
```

For more information, see the [async options docs](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt#async-options).

Comment: Also, you don't need to import ConfigModule if you have already imported it globally in your app module .i.e

        ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      expandVariables: true,
    }),

Comment: @SegunKess that's a pretty nice hint!

Comment: wiwth "expiresIn: 3600", I wasn't able to authorize. Adding the "s" to get "expiresIn: 3600s" solved the problem - such small one ...

Comment: From the docs: "A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default ("120" is equal to "120ms")." As this is quite confusing, I'd always prefer the expressive variant as string including the time unit.

Answer (score -1):

Or there is another solution, create an JwtStrategy class, something like this:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: config.session.secret,
            issuer: config.uuid,
            audience: config.session.domain
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

There you are able to pass `ConfigService` as a parameter to the constructor, but I'm using config just from plain file.

Then, don't forget to place it in array of providers in module.

Regards.

Comment: you can't pass the `ConfigService` here, because the use of `this` is not allowed in `super()`

Comment: que? [10 more to go]

Comment: if you pass the `ConfigService` in the constructor, you can't access it in the `super()` function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896505/this-is-not-allowed-before-superclass-constructor-invocation

Comment: and why would you need to access it by this there?

Comment: i was just replying to what you said... You're using a static config file. I'm just telling it won't work with the ConfigService, that's all

Comment: But even if you pass the ConfigService here you are able to use it without this, just by name of the argument.

Comment: It worked for me and I was able to access the configService from the constructor:
constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: configService.get<string>('jwt.secret'),
    });
  }