# How to import a registerAsync in a dynamic Nestjs module?

Tags: typescript, dynamic, import, module, nestjs

been looking into the dynamic modules using the Advanced NestJS: [**How to build completely dynamic NestJS modules.**](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370)

From what I've seen, most people use this guide to build a sync/async dynamic module.

But my question is, that if I use the registerAsync method, and my dynamic module needs to import HttpModule, and HttpModule's register-options are provided by my dynamic module.

How do you import a module within a dynamic module, where the options are provided by the dynamic module?
Or is it the wrong way to handle this issue? if so, how would you structure it?

---

Here's the code. Which is practically a carbon copy of the tutorial.
As you can see in the register method, it's simple - I just pass in the options.
registerAsync however, I'm having trouble figuring out what to do.

---

Any help is much appreciated :)

```
import { Module, DynamicModule, Provider, HttpModule } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InvoicesHealth } from "./invoices/invoices.health";
import { InvoicesResolver, InvoicesService } from "./invoices";
import {
  CustomerInvoicesOptions,
  CustomerInvoicesAsyncOptions,
  CustomerInvoicesOptionsFactory,
} from "./interfaces";
import { CUSTOMER_INVOICES_OPTIONS } from "./constants";
import { createCustomerInvoicesProviders } from "./providers/customer-invoices.providers";

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [InvoicesHealth, InvoicesResolver, InvoicesService],
  exports: [InvoicesHealth],
})
export class CustomerInvoicesModule {
  /**
   * Registers a configured customer-invoices Module for import into the current module
   */
  public static register(options: CustomerInvoicesOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      imports: [
        HttpModule.register({
          url: options.url,
          auth: {
            username: options.username,
            password: options.password,
          },
        }),
      ],
      module: CustomerInvoicesModule,
      providers: createCustomerInvoicesProviders(options),
    };
  }

  /**
   * Registers a configured customer-invoices Module for import into the current module
   * using dynamic options (factory, etc)
   */
  public static registerAsync(
    options: CustomerInvoicesAsyncOptions,
  ): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: CustomerInvoicesModule,
      imports: options.imports || [],
      providers: [...this.createProviders(options)],
    };
  }

  private static createProviders(
    options: CustomerInvoicesAsyncOptions,
  ): Provider[] {
    if (options.useExisting || options.useFactory) {
      return [this.createOptionsProvider(options)];
    }

    return [
      this.createOptionsProvider(options),
      {
        provide: options.useClass,
        useClass: options.useClass,
      },
    ];
  }

  private static createOptionsProvider(
    options: CustomerInvoicesAsyncOptions,
  ): Provider {
    if (options.useFactory) {
      return {
        provide: CUSTOMER_INVOICES_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: options.useFactory,
        inject: options.inject || [],
      };
    }

    // For useExisting...
    return {
      provide: CUSTOMER_INVOICES_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: async (optionsFactory: CustomerInvoicesOptionsFactory) =>
        await optionsFactory.createFtNestCustomerInvoicesOptions(),
      inject: [options.useExisting || options.useClass],
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the use case you're trying to achieve?

Comment: My module contains a resolver/service that communicates with a rest api using the HttpModule. So instead of having the user import a HttpModule and then also import my module, I want to internally import the HttpModule; so that the user only has to worry about importing my module - providing my module with the options needed to register the HttpModule (as shown in the **register** method above). My predicament is then, how do I formulate this same internal HttpModule register in the async method? :)

Or is this completely the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: I do have the exact same question. Looking for hours and hours now. Did you find an answer yet? I created a repo to try things out: https://github.com/MickL/nestjs-dynamic-modules-with-imports

Comment: @JóhannØsterø This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310397/3607051) work to  get the configurations from with in a module.

Answer (score 21):

Okay, buckle in, cause there isn't an easy answer, but there are *kind of* ways around it.

First and foremost, there's no way to call one module's asynchronous registration method from another module's asynchronous registration method. At least not using the asynchronous configuration that was passed in, so instead I'll show you what *can* be done.

#### Option One. `imports`

Probably the easiest of the three options that **still works** with the async registration method. The `imports` array that is passed to the asynchronous config is completely available in the module, so you can end up doing something like

```js
CustomerInvoicesModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: httpConfigFactory,
    }),
    ConfigModule
  ],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: customerInvoicesConfigFactory,
})
```

This will expose the `HttpService` in its full configuration. The only thing to be aware/careful of is making sure you're keeping track of the registration levels.

#### Option Two. `asyncConfigInterface`

This is the fun one. You can change your asynchronous config options to be something along the lines of

```js
export interface CustomInvoiceModuleAsyncOptions {
  http: HttpModuleAsyncOptions;
  useClass?: RegularValueHere;
  useFactory?: RegularValueHere;
  useValue?: RegularValueHere;
  inject: injectionArray;
  imports: importsArray;
}
```

And now in your `registerAsync` method, you can do

```js
static registerASync(options: CustomerInvoiceModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
  return {
    module: CustomerInvoicesModule,
    imports: [HttpModule.registerAsync(options.http)]
    providers: [...this.createProvider(options)],
    exports: [...this.createProvider(options)],
  }
}
```

Now, this means that the config is passed for the `HttpModule` inside of the options for your module, which kind of looks ugly, but it gets the options to the right module.

#### Option Three. `register/forRoot`

Just don't use the `ConfgModule` and use the `register` or `forRoot` methods directly. This way you can pass config values down quickly and easily. Very straightforward if you don't mind not using the `ConfigModule`.

Comment: Even tho I trust your word that it is not possible I just wanted to add the note if someone wants to find a solution I made a simple repo for testing around: https://github.com/MickL/nestjs-dynamic-modules-with-imports

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on Jay's answer, there may be an Option Four that works for you.

### Option Four. `extraProviders`

Not all modules support this (but `HttpModule` seems to - so you're in luck).

```
public static registerAsync(options: CustomerInvoicesAsyncOptions,): DynamicModule {
    const providers = this.createProviders(options);
    return {
      module: CustomerInvoicesModule,
      imports: [
          HttpModule.registerAsync({
              imports: options.imports || [],
              // Factory is passed the injected CustomerInvoicesOptions as argument
              // which is based on the result of the extra providers
              useFactory: async (options: CustomerInvoicesOptions) => ({
                  url: options.url,
                  auth: {
                      username: options.username,
                      password: options.password,
                  },
              }),
              inject: [CUSTOMER_INVOICES_OPTIONS],
              extraProviders: providers,
          }),
          ...(options.imports || []),
        ],
        providers: [...providers],
    };
}
```

Jay may be able to clarify if this approach is correct, but it seems to work for me.

### Fallback. `@Global()/export`

Instances where the module does not expose an `extraProviders` property in their `AsyncOptions` you may be able to circumvent this by making the module `@Global()` and exporting the `CUSTOMER_INVOICES_OPTIONS` provider.

e.g for the `PassportModule` (which unfortunately does not expose an `extraProviders` property)

```
@Global()
@Module({...})
export class CustomerInvoicesModule {
    ....
    public static registerAsync(options: CustomerInvoicesAsyncOptions,): DynamicModule {
        return {
            module: CustomerInvoicesModule,
            imports: [
                PassportModule.registerAsync({
                    useFactory: async (options: CustomerInvoicesOptions) => ({
                        defaultStrategy: options.oauthEnabled ? 'jwt' : 'no-auth',
                    }),
                    inject: [CUSTOMER_INVOICES_OPTIONS],
                }),
                ...(options.imports || []),
            ],
            providers: [...this.createProviders(options)],
            exports: [CUSTOMER_INVOICES_OPTIONS],
        };
    }
    ....
```

This `@Global()` approach also works, but isn't particularly nice.

Other things I have tried, which fail:

- Circular import of the outer dynamic module into the inner, with the options provider key injected - the injected provider key cannot be resolved.
- Same circular import, but with a `forwardRef(() => MyModule)` - this always fails with a `metatype is not a constructor` error.

Hope this insight helps, and any NestJS experts can correct issues with either approach.

Comment: Some other modules, like (Microservice) ClientModule, dont need to be imported. Instead there is a function `ClientProxyFactory.create(options)`. In that case it works with registerAsync, too. But for example the CacheModule does not have this.

Comment: Huh, I've never seen this `extraProviders` used, but it is indeed there for the `HttpModule`. Thanks for expanding on my answer. It would be interesting to see how many more modules have this kind of setup

Comment: I've noticed quite a lot of the official/built-in NestJS modules do have this `extraProviders` defined, though its intended use isn't documented anywhere. It would be nice to see this, and better documentation for what is quite a boilerplatey setup that dynamic/async modules become.