# NestJS, Import values from external modules

Tags: nestjs

Consider following structure of files:

```
/src/common/common.module.ts
/src/common/common.service.ts (CommonService)

/src/myclass/myclass.module.ts
/src/myclass/myclass.service.ts (MyClassService)
/src/myclass/another-class.module.ts
/src/myclass/another-class.service.ts (AnotherClassService)
```

Here I want to pass a variable/some_value from following files:

```
/src/myclass/myclass.module.ts
/src/myclass/another-classs.module.ts
```

to consturctor of `/src/common/common.service.ts`

My use-case is that CommonService class(which is inside /src/myclass/myclass.module.ts) will initialize certain variables differently in it's constructor based on where it is used.

So for example if my CommonService class is used inside MyClassService then I want to pass certain value lets say "1" and if CommonService is used inside AnotherClassService then I want pass value "0" to constructor of CommonService.

Is this possible to do, if so how can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Have written an answer. Can you check if it works for you?

Comment: @RobinThomas thanks, yeah I checked I am looking into this a bit more. I will accept after trying this out in my code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Next.js custom provider for this: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers

In your `MyClassService` module, you create `CommonService` using:

```
{
  provide: CommonService,
  useFactory: (/* injectables for CommonService constructor */) => {
    return new CommonService(/* injectables for CommonService constructor */, /* pass 1 here */);
  },
  inject: [/* injectables for CommonService constructor */],
}
```

In your `AnotherClassService` module, you create `CommonService` using:

```
{
  provide: CommonService,
  useFactory: (/* injectables for CommonService constructor */) => {
    return new CommonService(/* injectables for CommonService constructor */, /* pass 0 here */);
  },
  inject: [/* injectables for CommonService constructor */],
}
```

---

Within the `inject` array, you need to pass any services/injectables (created by Nest.js dependency injection), so that you don't have to create objects of those services/injectables yourselves.

Comment: Although technically you are right that this would allow us to inject dynamic value to CommonModule this solution would mean that I will need to inject dependencies of CommonService everywhere I want to use that class. A better solution would be to use nestjs dyanmic modules as explained by "Jay McDoniel" here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356440/how-to-import-a-registerasync-in-a-dynamic-nestjs-module