# How to access derived class members in abstract implementation of method?

Tags: typescript

How is it that `Derived` is perfectly happy to call `this.log()` but somehow doesn't know about `this.value`? I'd have thought `value` would be set before `super()` is called?

How can `Derived` have a value set by the constructor and still be accessed by `this.log()`?

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract map() : void;    

    constructor()
    {
        this.map();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base 
{
    constructor(private value : string)
    {
        super();        
    }

    protected map(): void 
    {
        this.log();
    }

    log()
    {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

const derived = new Derived("Hello world"); // Alerts "undefined"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgKAG88ESEAHKAewh3hwBMFRIZ4EBbYMgCgEoEAXAgBulAJb0A3KQR5ipWJQB2LAK7xKUPvJJEZMiAAsxYAHScevSToQBfPPbwo0GACI4oY4QwQ4AHjRK9BjYYDiyegrKahpaFF7ANCLAyKrhQixiSgDmvDaR+ghgqmQefNKFsjKOMhTUtDSMFnxCohJVpAX6RiamyJTZ5TY1pP2DeTJdMikeENw9ZsIpaVbDDnKKKoj0Hl4+ALwISjgA7gjunt703ABEABI4yP0IJ5rI9DdWCAD03wgAgshZhgbqogjgAGZZBg3IA)

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not asking how to implement an abstract method in general, I'm asking about how can I invoke the concrete method from the constructor of the abstract class that uses a value defined by the constructor of the concrete class *without* defining the constructor parameter(s) on the abstract class since every concrete instance needs a variety of different types and values which would make the constructor of the abstract class quite absurd.

I also would like to avoid having the consumer of the abstract class having to remember to call `map()`, and ideally, the instance of the concrete class should be valid once it's initialized.

Comment: There are so many posts about this on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13333489/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40931506/5468463, etc... Have you looked?

Comment: @Vega Indeed, but my google fu failed me. It simply may not be possible. That particular example isn't trying to call an abstract method from the constructor (which I think is bad practice but... that's probably the root cause of the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fabrizio Gargiulo and @Shubham Wajo already mentioned the root problem which is from `super()` initialization before `this.value` assignment, but I'd give another way to fix it with a [call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack) trick.

Javascript only has a single thread, so all functions will proceed synchronously from top to bottom. `super()` is not an exception for it, but we can delay the execution with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#late_timeouts) for the call stack completed (all initializations are done).

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract map() : void;    

    constructor()
    {
        //this will run after `Derived` initalization completed
        setTimeout(() => this.map())
    }
}

class Derived extends Base 
{
    constructor(private value : string)
    {
        super();        
    }

    protected map(): void 
    {
        this.log();
    }

    log()
    {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

const derived = new Derived("Hello world"); //"Hello world"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgKAG88ESEAHKAewh3hwBMFRIZ4EBbYMgCgEoEAXAgBulAJb0A3KQR5ipWJQB2LAK7xKUPvJJEZMsDggAVMexyVVEbnwQBeAHwIIACzFgAdJx69eOhAC%20eEF4KGgYACI4UGLCDAg4AB40SvQY2IayegrKahpaFLHANCLAyKo4gggsYkoA5n4y2frVqmTRfNItsjIhMhTUtDSM3nxCohI9pM36ru4eyJR1nf59pIvLjdP%20MmXR1nOewmUVvJKrwXKKKoj00bHxdghKOADuCFExcfTcAEQAEjhkIsEK9NMh6L8zggAPQwhAAQWQ%20wwv1UqRwADNagxfkA)

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you call `super()` the `value` property is not yet initialised and it is mandatory to call parent `class`'s constructor which means you must call `super()` at the top of the constructor.

So as you are calling `map` method inside the `Base` class the `value` property is not yet initialised and thats why you are getting `undefined`.

Execute the following code and see the flow:

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract map() : void;    

    constructor()
    {
        console.log("abstract base constructor")
        this.map();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base 
{
    constructor(private value : string)
    {
        super();
        console.log("value initialized",this.value)  
    }

    protected map(): void 
    {
        console.log("map function call")
        this.log();
    }

    log()
    {
        console.log("log functon call")
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

const derived = new Derived("Hello world"); // Alerts "undefined"
```

It's a good idea to call `map` method inside the `Derived` class constructor after calling `super()`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgKAG88ESEAHKAewh3hwBMFRIZ4EBbYMgCgEoEAXAgBulAJb0A3KQR5ipWJQB2LAK7xKUPvJJEZMxSsrIcAOmSUA5twBEzaHEQhcSZWo1QbvHfogALMTBTTh5eSR8AXzwovBQ0DAARHCgxYQYEHAAPGiV6DGwwHFk9BTdodQhNbgpU4BoRYGRVIqEWMSVLbxkS-QQwVTJkvnDekkMwYzMLaxthRuaEdrEIMUaxAC8GGwAaf0DTOaacflkZGJkKaloaRhC%20IVEJU9Ie-XHJ8ytbEIQAM1UlPAxMokI1kF4fDI9kFpsNInIZLCui9IaUjCZPjNpn8ARolKDkODkb1GskINxoQd5scRqQojFxoh6MlUukALwIJQ4ADuCCSKTS9FsAAkcITKAhuZpkPQvNIAPTyhAAQRMUAgGBsAOZv3aWyAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still a little confused to why Dervied.map() can know about this.log() but NOT about this.value :/ I know it doesn't, I just don't quite understand why it would be implemented that way. 

I'd prefer not to have all the derived classes manually calling this.map() after their super call if at all possible, but maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, inside the Derived constructor, the first thing you can call is super(), only after you can initialize your Derived parameter "value". The problem is that you call this.map() before that value is ever initialized and for this reason the Alert shows undefined.

So you have two options in my opinion:

1. You declare a protected property called "value" (or "_value") in Base class, and you init it before the this.map() statement.
2. You declare and init such property in the Derived class, but, this.map() should be executed in Derived constructor.

**Solution 1**

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract map() : void;    

    constructor(protected value : string)
    {
        this.map();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base 
{
    constructor(protected value : string)
    {
        super(value);    
    }

    protected map(): void 
    {
        this.log();
    }

    log()
    {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}
```

const derived = new Derived("Hello world"); // Alerts "undefined"

**Solution 2**

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract map() : void;    

}

class Derived extends Base 
{
    constructor(private value : string)
    {
        super();              
        this.map();
    }

    protected map(): void 
    {
        this.log();
    }

    log()
    {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}

const derived = new Derived("Hello world"); // Hello world
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!. In Solution 1, Base cannot require value because the derived class may have a variety of different needs (I just used a single string param to illustrate, when in fact each derived class may need 0-3 wildly different values) 

In Solution 2, this requires the derived class implementations to be aware that they must call map() themselves rather than just providing the implementation for it. I'd prefer to keep the implementation tighter but... if I can't figure out anything tighter I'll probably do this and mark it as the answer.