# How to properly define a abstract method in a class that IDE will complain if abstract method is not implemented ?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can i properly define a abstract method in a abstract class ? I want that IDE tell me that implementation of that abstract method is a must.

**I tried the following, but without success:**

```
export abstract class MyAbstractClass {

   /**
    * @abstract
    */
   public submit() {
      throw new Error('This class must be implemented')
   }
}
```

> The question is: how can we make the IDE to complain if you don't
>   implement the abstract method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring abstract method in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333489/declaring-abstract-method-in-typescript)

Comment: can't you just add the `abstract` keyword instead of `public` ?

Comment: `abstract makeSound(input : string) : string;` where `input` is a param, first `string` is typechecking and second `string` is the return type

Comment: @JacobHeater is not duplicated. I'm just using the syntax from there, but i want to know if there's a way to integrate it with IDE (Visual Studio Code for example)

Comment: @AndreiTodorut That would require you to actually correctly define the `abstract` method, therefore making this question a duplicate. `How can i properly define a abstract method in a abstract class ?`

Comment: @JacobHeater, updated the question title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
export abstract class MyAbstractClass {
   // we shouldn't declare the body of abstract method
   abstract submit(): void;
}

//...

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
}
```

And you will see ide complain:
[image]

What you're doing in your question example - is a well known ES6 hack for [emulating abstract classes](https://gist.github.com/Zodiase/af44115098b20d69c531). But TypeScript supports abstract classes out of the box. For more details, you can check the [official documentation on classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Also created a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jirhhz?file=index.ts), you can check it out.

Comment: @sherlock92, ok but when you separate those 2 classes in files the IDE will not complain about missing implementation for abstract method.

Comment: I don't see any issues here. Check the updated [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jirhhz?file=index.ts) - I've separated classes in two files and still get complain.