# Java to JavaScript conversion

Tags: javascript, oop

I've done many attempts to understand OOP in JavaScript without success.

All articles I've read so far are very confuse and not explain succintly OOP in JS

As a last attempt to understand OOP in JavaScript, can someone translate to JS the following code, pleas?

```
public class Base
{
    public String firstName;  // public scope to simplify
    public String lastName;   // the same as above

    Base(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }
}


public class Derived extends Base
{
    public int age;  // public scope to simplify

    Derived(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

Inside main()

```
    Derived person = new Derived("John", "Doe", 25);

    System.out.println("My name is " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + " and I have " + person.age + " years old.");
```

Output:

```
My name is John Doe and I have 25 years old.
```

Can you please convert this to JavaScript?

Another question: Can we have polimorphism in JavaScript?

Comment: I'll try to convert the code above without success as you may see.

Comment: hey man, its a scripting language. you CANNOT do anything like this in javascript

Comment: @AmanChhabra: Ok, but at least something equivalent. Even thought JS !=Java OOP is always OOP, I think

Comment: If you add a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar with your attempt at a solution you may get more responses/solutions here.

Comment: @AmanChhabra, yes you can, [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597769/how-do-i-create-an-abstract-base-class-in-javascript) shows many ways of dealing with inheritance in javascript.

Comment: @user3224159 as you said you have read a lot on this topic. But maybe you haven't come across this playground yet to explore JS OO thinking http://www.objectplayground.com

Comment: @user3224159 yes inheritance is possible in javascript. I have added a snippet for the same in my answer

Comment: I know this wasn't the question, hence me not putting this as the answer, but here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLLJU/) showing how easy it is done using TypeScript, which compiles to JavaScript.  I've commented out the original code I wrote in TS and left the compiled javascript in the fiddle.  You can play around with TypeScript [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/)

Answer (score 6):

Since, JavaScript is prototype based, there's no such thing as Class. You can use Constructors (*functions*) to create custom data types and provide inheritance by prototype.

```
function Base (firstName, lastName) {
    // same as public in Java
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

function Derived (firstName, lastName, age) {
    // same as calling super class in Java, and you should explicitly bind this
    Base.apply(this, arguments);
    this.age = age;
}

// same as extends in Java, you just override Derived.prototype with super class prototype and you should explicitly set constructor if you want later check instanceof.
Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype, {
     // if you omit this line than instanceof Derived would be false, since instanceof check by prototype chain constructors.
    constructor: {
        value: Derived
    }
});

var person = new Derived("John", "Doe", 25);

console.log(person instanceof Derived); // true
console.log(person instanceof Base); // true

console.log("My name is " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName + " and I have " + person.age + " years old.");
```

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/FYwV8/2/)

---

About **polymorphism**, if you are asking about method overloading there's no such thing, but, since javascript is weakly typed dynamic language you can achieve same result with checking [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) length and typeof of that arguments. *I believe that other concepts of polymorphism working same as in Java.*
Simple e.g:

```
function bar(a, b) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) { 
        var isInts = [].every.call(arguments, function(val) {
            return !isNaN(val);
        });
        if (isInts) {
            console.log(a + b);
        }
    } else if (arguments.length > 2) {
        console.log([].join.call(arguments, ""));
    }
}

bar(2, 5);
bar("Hello", ", ", "world", "!");
```

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/S24kr/)

---

Also look at:
[A re-introduction to JavaScript (JS Tutorial)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FA_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)
[Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
[Inheritance and the prototype chain MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: THANK YOU (in bold letters). You ansewr my question. I can´t give +1 because SO requires 15 reputation

Comment: read this to understand how prototype inheritance works in more detail: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/