# How to implement abstract factory in js?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I want to implement very simple abstract factory pattern but I am facing this error.
Also am I doing something wrong with my code? How can I improve this to make it work properly?

Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor"

Comment: Drop the `MakePizza` class and create two classes implementing its interface (i.e. having a `createPizza` method). Keep it abstract!

Comment: Neither your `Pizza` nor your `MakePizza` class are properly [abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29480569/1048572)

Comment: A "simple abstract factory" with only a single method doesn't need to be an abstract factory at all. You could use the simple normal factory pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `super()` inside constructor:

```
class MakeMeatPizza extends MakePizza {
    constructor() {
        super();
        super.createPizza("meat");
    }
}
```

So thanks to [this beautiful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079103):

> The rules for ES2015 (ES6) classes basically come down to:
>
> - In a child class constructor, this cannot be used until super is called.
> - ES6 class constructors MUST call super if they are subclasses, or they must explicitly return some object to take the place of the one
>   that was not initialized.

And the code looks like this:

```js
class Pizza {
    constructor(name,size,type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.type = type;
    }

    prepare() {
        console.log("prepare");
    }
    bake() {
        console.log("bake");
    }
    deliver() {
        console.log("deliver");
    }
}

class MeatPizza extends Pizza {
    constructor() {
        super("Chicago style pizza", "Large", "Meat")
    }
}

class VegePizza extends Pizza {
    constructor() {
        super("Only natural", "Large", "Vegetarian")
    }
}

class MakePizza {
    createPizza(type) {
        switch (type) {
            case "meat":
                return new MeatPizza()
            case "vege":
                return new VegePizza()
            default:
                throw new Error("Something went wrong...");
        }
    }
}

class MakeMeatPizza extends MakePizza {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    create() {
        return this.createPizza("meat")
    }
}

class MakeVegePizza extends MakePizza {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    create() {
        return this.createPizza("vege")
    }
}

class OrderPizza {

}

const test = new MakeVegePizza().create();
console.log(test)
```

Comment: but why am I getting an empty object back when I do `const test = new MakeVegePizza()`. I have to make it like this `const test = new MakeVegePizza().createPizza('vege');` to get pizza details

Comment: @squnk please, see my updated answer. Constructor should return nothing as goal of constructor is to construct object. I've edited code