# How to create Abstract base class in JavaScript that can't be Instantiated

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a class

```
function Node() {
    //implementation
}
```

and another class

```
function AttributionalNode() {
    this.prototype.setAttr = function (attr) {
        this.atText = attr;
    };
}

AttributionalNode.prototype = new Node();
AttributionalNode.prototype.constructor = AttributionalNode;
```

How to make class Node() so it can't be instantiated?
e.g when I try

```
var node = new Node();
```

So it throws an Exception?

Comment: Put `throw new Exception()` in the constructor, maybe? I dunno if that's valid in Javascript.

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to set prototype properties in the constructor function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This would work:

```js
function Node() {
    if (this.constructor === Node) {
        throw new Error("Cannot instantiate this class");
    }
}

function AttributionalNode() {
    Node.call(this); // call super
}

AttributionalNode.prototype = Object.create(Node.prototype);
AttributionalNode.prototype.setAttr = function (attr) {
    this.atText = attr;
};
AttributionalNode.prototype.constructor = AttributionalNode;

var attrNode = new AttributionalNode();
console.log(attrNode);
new Node();
```

Note: you cannot refer to `this.prototype` inside the constructor, as the prototype is only a property of the constructor function, not of the instances.

Also, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) for a good article on how to properly extend JS classes.

Comment: It throughs error when some class try to inherit from Node()

Comment: @AlexandrSargsyan It does not. I updated the example to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 57):

In JavaScript engines that support ECMAScript 2015 (aka ES6) class syntax, this can be accomplished using the `new.target` meta-property:

```
function Node() {
   if (new.target === Node) throw TypeError("new of abstract class Node");
}
```

or  using class syntax:

```
class Node {
   constructor () {
      if (new.target === Node) throw TypeError("new of abstract class Node");
   }
}
```

in either case, just define `AttributionalNode` as:

```
class AttributionalNode extends Node {
   constructor () {
      super();
   }
   setAttr(attr) {
      this.atText = attr;
   }
}

new Node();               // will throw TypeError
new AttributionalNode();  // works fine
```

For a more detailed explanation of `new.target` see section 4.2 of [this document](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for `new.target`?

Comment: If you wish to know whether it supports or not: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#new.target  . At this moment, no support, as stated.

Comment: [MDN: new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)

Comment: Is there any difference between `new.target` and `this.constructor`?

Comment: @DonaldDuck probably not, but there might be a case where `this` is not available yet.

Answer (score 8):

Adapting @levi's answer, you can go with a similar solution for using with ES6 today (as `new.target` isn't established yet):

You can see it running on Babel's repl: http://bit.ly/1cxYGOP

```
class Node {
    constructor () {
      if (this.constructor === Node) 
          throw new Error("Cannot instantiate Base Class");
    }

    callMeBaby () {
      console.log("Hello Baby!");
    }
}

class AttributionalNode extends Node {
  constructor () {
    super();
    console.log("AttributionalNode instantiated!");
  }
}

let attrNode = new AttributionalNode();
attrNode.callMeBaby();

let node = new Node();
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the question has a *javascript* tag, because nowadays a lot of projects are using *typescript* on top of JS, it's worth noting that TS has [support for abstract classes and methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes) out of the box

```js
abstract class Animal {
    abstract makeSound(): void;
    move(): void {
        console.log("roaming the earth...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on these comments, I wrote this

```
class AbstractClass {
    constructor() {
        if(new.target === AbstractClass || this.__proto__.__proto__.constructor === AbstractClass)
            throw new TypeError("Cannot construct "+ this.constructor.name + " class instances directly");
        let exceptions = {};
        let currProto = this;
        while(currProto.constructor !== AbstractClass ) {
            for(let method of (currProto.constructor.abstractMethods || [])) {
                if("function" !== typeof(this[method]))
                    exceptions[method] = currProto.constructor.name;
            }
            currProto = currProto.__proto__;
        }
        if(0 !== Object.keys(exceptions).length) {
            let exceptionsArray = [];
            for(let method in exceptions) {
                exceptionsArray.push( exceptions[method] + "." + method);
            }
            exceptionsArray.sort();
            throw new TypeError("Must override the following methods: " + exceptionsArray.join(", "));
        }
    }
    }
```

Usage:

```
class MyAbstractClass1 extends AbstractClass {
    static abstractMethods = [
        "myMethod1", // (x:string, y:string): string
        "myMethod2" // (y:string, z:string): string 
    ]
}

class MyAbstractClass2 extends MyAbstractClass1 {
    static abstractMethods = [
        "myMethod3", // (x:string, y:string): string
        "myMethod4" // (y:string, z:string): string 
    ]
}

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass2 {
    myMethod1(x, y){return "apple"}
}

new MyClass()
//Error
```