# SyntaxError using Babel and JSX when using class

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jsx

I'm trying to create classes using webpack, babel and jsx

```
import Observable from '../../observable';


abstract class AbstractClient implements Observable  {
    var _name: string,
    var _config: object,

    function constructor(config: object) : variant,

    ...
}
export default AbstractClient;
```

And here is the error I get:

```
ERROR in ./app/adapter/AbstractAdapter/aclient.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/vinz243/Documents/nTorrent/app/adapter/AbstractAdapter/aclient.jsx: Unexpected token (5:9)
  3 | 
  4 | 
> 5 | abstract class AbstractClient implements Observable  {
    |          ^
  6 |   var _name: string,
  7 |   var _config: object,
  8 |
```

My babel presets

```
 presets:['es2015','stage-0','react']
```

Comment: I believe `'react'` needs to come first in your presets list.

Comment: @MikeC I assume it doesn't change anthing it worked well before with react templates and so

Comment: Your code is Typescript, Babel does not know how to handle that.

Comment: Are you trying to use typescript or pure ES2015?  If you want to use typescript, you should use a typescript loader in webpack instead of the babel loader I assume you are using.

Comment: I am using JSX I believe. https://jsx.github.io/doc/tutorial.html#classes-and-interfaces

Comment: Oh that's confusing. You are trying to use a language called JSX, which appears to be unrelated to React's JSX markup format. This definitely isn't going to work in Babel. It also looks a lot like typescript.

Comment: Ah. Why the hell do they give the same name to two different things but with same nature and same purpose? Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no syntax support in ES2015 for abstract classes, that's why you get an unexpected token error.  abstract is not a keyword in es2015 either, so the interpreter is probably interpreting abstract as a variable name.

There are methods of implementing an abstract class pattern in Javascript.

- [Does ECMAScript 6 have a convention for abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480569/does-ecmascript-6-have-a-convention-for-abstract-classes)
- [How to create Abstract base class in JavaScript that can't be Instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559225/how-to-create-abstract-base-class-in-javascript-that-cant-be-instantiated)

Comment: You're not wrong, but there're more to it. This is Typescript, not ES6.

Comment: You are right, I should have noticed because OP is using implements as well.  Confusing as there's a jsx tag instead of typescript.  Probably OP is confused as well